# Clean way to glob for files recursively in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Given the following directory structure:

```
myDir
   file1.c
   file2.c
   subDirA
      file3.c
   subDirB
      file4.c
```

I want to find `*.c` files with glob, or another similarly efficient method (not using the `os.walk` method documented elsewhere).

The problem I encounter is that, given the path `myDir` I can't get all `c` files recursively in one line of code.

```
glob.glob('myDir/*.c', recursive=True)
```

only yields `file1` and `file2`. And

```
glob.glob('myDir/**/*.c', recursive=True
```

only yields `file3` and `file4`.

Is there a nice clean way to combine those two statements into one? It sure seems like there would be.

Comment: Why dont you wanna use `os.walk`?

Comment: `glob.glob('myDir/**/*.c', recursive=True)` works for me...

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: It does work as described and noted here. I had accidentally left off a recursive=True in one of my tests that prompted this question. Dumb error on my part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path
Path('/to/myDir').glob('**/*.c')
```

As for why glob didn't work for you:

```
glob.glob('myDir/**/*.c', recursive=True)
             ^
             |___ you had a lower d here
                  https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49022163/1
```

Make sure you're running it from within the parent of myDir and that your Python version is 3.5+.

Comment: While I do love `pathlib`, `glob.glob('myDir/**/*.c', recursive=True)` should work, at least, it works for me when I create a directory tree with the same structure...

Comment: Yeah I think OP probably had a typo.  Works for me too.

Comment: I believe MacOSX HFS+ file system (and maybe the new one with High Sierra) are case insensitive "but case preserving" (something I just now discovered when I tried it with the lower-case version... ugh).

Comment: Who said OP is on macOS?

Comment: That's a possibility, is all I'm saying. What's even *weirder* is that it is giving file3 and file4, as per the OP. I feel like it must be some sort of typo to produce that behavior...

Comment: typo? `glob.glob('mydir/**/*.c', recursive=True` you think ? :) it doesn't even have the last parenthese

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  for result only seeing file3 and file4, a typo could have possibly been 'myDir/*/*.c'

Comment: why designed like that? why need `**/*.` if `recursive=True` is already set? it's not *clean*.